# Image not being added to panel - Java

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel, imageicon

I am trying to practice JLabel/JFrame and I am have trouble having my image "key2.png" appear.
I am using Visual Studio Code and I have both my code and the image in the same src folder.

`

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("key2.png");

    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setText("Hello");
    label.setIcon(icon);

    JPanel redPanel = new JPanel();
    redPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    redPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 250);

    JPanel bluePanel = new JPanel();
    bluePanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    bluePanel.setBounds(250, 0, 250, 250);

    JPanel greenPanel = new JPanel();
    greenPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
    greenPanel.setBounds(0, 250, 500, 250);
    
    
    MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame();   //makes frame
    myFrame.setLayout(null);  //disable defualt layout
    myFrame.add(redPanel);
    redPanel.add(label);   //add text and image to panel
    myFrame.add(bluePanel);
    myFrame.add(greenPanel);
  }
}
```

`

Output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nh890.png)

Expecting to see a black key image in the red panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need to put the image into the Project folder. As the Program running directory is not the source directory.
Put it into a subfolder like textures and reference it with the path like

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("textures/key2.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `new ImageIcon("key2.png")` with

```
new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("key2.png"))
```

and make sure your `key2.png` image file is copied into the directory that contains the `Main.class` file before running your application.

`Class.getResource` finds application resource files and should be used for files that are meant to be distributed with the application. See the [getResource API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JPanel and working with spring try the below method which turns the image to a swing component. Hence it becomes subject to layout conditions like any other component:

```
BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("path-to-file"));
JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
add(picLabel);
```